# ¿Cuál es el propósito de las clases locales en java?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código de la documentación de Oracle de java:

```
public class LocalClassExample {

    static String regularExpression = "[^0-9]";

    public static void validatePhoneNumber(
        String phoneNumber1, String phoneNumber2) {

        final int numberLength = 10;

        // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

        // int numberLength = 10;

        class PhoneNumber {

            String formattedPhoneNumber = null;

            PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
                // numberLength = 7;
                String currentNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(
                  regularExpression, "");
                if (currentNumber.length() == numberLength)
                    formattedPhoneNumber = currentNumber;
                else
                    formattedPhoneNumber = null;
            }

            public String getNumber() {
                return formattedPhoneNumber;
            }

            // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

//            public void printOriginalNumbers() {
//                System.out.println("Original numbers are " + phoneNumber1 +
//                    " and " + phoneNumber2);
//            }
        }

        PhoneNumber myNumber1 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber1);
        PhoneNumber myNumber2 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber2);

        // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

//        myNumber1.printOriginalNumbers();

        if (myNumber1.getNumber() == null) 
            System.out.println("First number is invalid");
        else
            System.out.println("First number is " + myNumber1.getNumber());
        if (myNumber2.getNumber() == null)
            System.out.println("Second number is invalid");
        else
            System.out.println("Second number is " + myNumber2.getNumber());

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        validatePhoneNumber("123-456-7890", "456-7890");
    }
}
```

En esta parte de la [documentación oficial de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html)

> **Local classes are classes that are defined in a block, which is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces. You
>   typically find local classes defined in the body of a method.**

entiendo que una clase local son clases definidas en a bloque, etc., pero no entiendo su propósito en general.

- ¿En qué las podría usar?
- ¿Son similares a las clases anónimas de java o son diferentes?

Comment: Normalmente las clases internas son utilizadas para realizar pequeñas organizaciones de datos y lógica dentro de un bloque de datos y lógica mayor. Esa lógica y datos interna vive dentro de la instancia mayor, por tanto, la idea es que sean usadas para cosas muy concretas dentro de una organización mayor. Al menos eso es lo que yo entiendo

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### ¿Qué es una clase local?

Según la [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html):

> Las clases locales son clases que se definen en un *bloque*, que es un
>   grupo de cero o más declaraciones entre `{ }` equilibrados.
>   Normalmente se encuentran  definidas en el cuerpo de un método.

Una clase local se declara localmente dentro de un bloque de código Java, en lugar de como miembro de una clase. Normalmente, una clase local se define dentro de un método, pero también se puede definir dentro de un inicializador estático o un inicializador de instancia de una clase.

Debido a que todos los bloques de código Java aparecen dentro de las definiciones de clase, todas las clases locales se anidan dentro de las clases que contienen. Por esta razón, las clases locales comparten muchas de las características de las clases de miembros. Sin embargo, suele ser más apropiado pensar en ellas como una clase enteramente separada de clase interna. Una clase local tiene aproximadamente la misma relación con una clase de miembro que una variable local tiene con una variable de instancia de clase.

La característica de definición de una clase local es que es local a un bloque de código. Como una variable local, una clase local sólo es válida dentro del ámbito definido por su bloque de inclusión.

Si por ejemplo una clase miembro se utiliza sólo dentro de un único método de su clase  contenedora, normalmente no hay razón para que no se pueda codificar como una clase local, en lugar de una clase miembro.

El ejemplo de más abajo muestra cómo podemos modificar el método enumerate () de la clase LinkedStack para que defina Enumerator como una clase local en lugar de una clase de miembro. Haciendo esto, movemos la definición de la clase incluso más cerca a donde se utiliza y esperanzadamente mejoramos mucho más la claridad del código. Para mayor brevedad, el ejemplo muestra sólo el método `enumerate()`, no toda la clase `LinkedStack` que lo contiene.

```
// Este método crea y retorna un objeto Enumeration
public java.util.Enumeration enumerate() {

  // Aquí se define Enumerator  como una clase local
  class Enumerator implements java.util.Enumeration {
    Linkable current;
    public Enumerator() { current = head; }
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {  return (current != null); }
    public Object nextElement() {
      if (current == null) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
      Object value = current;
      current = current.getNext();
      return value;
    }
  }

  // Ahora retorna una instancia de la clase Enumerator definida más arriba 
  return new Enumerator();
}
```

---

#### Características

Características de las clases locales

Las clases locales tienen las siguientes características interesantes:

- Al igual que las clases miembros, las clases locales están asociadas con una instancia de contención y pueden acceder a todos los miembros, incluidos los miembros privados, de la clase contenedora.
- Además de acceder a los campos definidos por la clase contenedora, las clases locales pueden acceder a cualquier variable local, parámetros de método o parámetros de excepción que estén dentro del alcance de la definición de método local y declarados finales (`final`).

---

#### Restricciones

Las clases locales están sujetas a las siguientes restricciones:

- Una clase local es visible sólo dentro del bloque que lo define; nunca se puede usar fuera de ese bloque.
- Las clases locales no pueden ser declaradas públicas, protegidas, privadas o estáticas. Estos modificadores son para miembros de clases; no se permiten con declaraciones de variables locales o declaraciones de clases locales.
- Al igual que las clases miembro, y por las mismas razones, las clases locales no pueden contener campos estáticos, métodos o clases. La única excepción es para constantes que se declaran estáticas y finales.
- Las interfaces no se pueden definir localmente.
- Una clase local, como una clase miembro, no puede tener el mismo nombre que cualquiera de sus clases adjuntas.
- Como se mencionó anteriormente, una clase local puede usar las variables locales, parámetros de método e incluso parámetros de excepción que están en su ámbito, pero sólo si dichas variables o parámetros son declarados finales. Esto se debe a que la duración de una instancia de una clase local puede ser mucho más larga que la ejecución del método en el que se define la clase. Por esta razón, una clase local debe tener una copia interna privada de todas las variables locales que utiliza (estas copias son generadas automáticamente por el compilador). La única manera de asegurar que la variable local y la copia privada son siempre la misma es insistir en que la variable local es final.

---

#### ¿Cuándo usarlas?

La [doc de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html) dice lo siguiente

> Utilícelas si necesita crear más de una instancia de una clase,
>   acceder a su constructor o introducir un nuevo tipo con nombre
>   (porque, por ejemplo, debe invocar métodos adicionales más adelante).

---

#### Enlaces útiles

- [Documentación de Java: Clases locales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html)
- [Clases locales en docstore.mik.ua](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_11.htm) (parte de esta respuesta es traducida de ese interesante artículo)

#### Taxonomía de Clases

Esta imagen muestra la taxonomía de las clases en Java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 8):

> son similares a las clases anonimas de java o son diferentes?

Son similares en que, fuera del código donde están definidas, no puedes hacer referencia a ellas.

> en general en que las podria usar?

La diferencia es que con una clase anónima no puedes hacer referencia a ella ni siquiera donde las defines; solo puedes crear una instancia.

El código te muestra un buen ejemplo; creas varias instancias de `PhoneNumber` y defines variables con ese tipo. Con las clases anónimas te encontrarías con que:

- Solo puedes crear una instancia para cada clase
- No puedes definir una variable de esa clase, sólo puedes usar una superclase (eso hace que, aunque posible, definir nuevos métodos públicos en una clase anónima no tenga sentido; salvo que uses *reflection* no podrás invocarlos).

Dicho lo dicho, yo personalmente soy partidario de no abusar de clases anónimas y locales por cuestiones de legibilidad, y en el caso de las locales siempre prefiero usar una clase incrustada (*nested*), definida a nivel de clase. Pero es una cuestión de preferencia.

Answer (score 4):

El proposito de una clase anidada es , para que lo entiendas, un metodo con la suficiente comlejidad como para decidir convertirla en clase, de esta forma el comportamiento es diferente, una vez dicho esto, te respondo:

la clase anidada solo existe mientras exista la clase externa,
  no puedes hacer un huevo si romper la cascara, eso lo explica todo